# Silverstripe Extending Controller Actions

Tags: php, model-view-controller, silverstripe

I'm trying to add a Controller Action to the Page_Controller class via an extension.

The desired result is to be able to go to `www.mysite.com/setlanguage/spanish` for instance and have that update the site's language to spanish via a browser cookie.

However I'm failry new to Extensions in SilverStripe and so far when I visit the link to the controller action all I get is a 404 error.

Please take a look at my code...

```
class Page_ControllerLanguageExtension extends Extension {

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'setLanguage'
    );

    public function setLanguage(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

        $requestedLanguage = $request->param('ID');
        $languageCookie = new Cookie;
        $languageCookie->set('site_language', $requestedLanguage);

        return $this->owner->RedirectBack();

    }
}
```

And I'm calling in the extension with a YML config file:

```
Page_Controller:
  extensions:
    - Page_ControllerLanguageExtension
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try calling `www.mysite.com/home/setlanguage/spanish` or `www.mysite.com/[page-url-segment]/setlanguage/spanish`. You're code looks good. I think the only problem is you can't call an action on the home page without the URL segment.

Comment: looks right. If you need the url `/setlanguage/spanish/` you need to route your controller to `setlanguage` and get the param in the `index()` method.

Comment: Simple as that! Perfect, thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you need `/setlanguage/<language>` as the url you have to route the url `/setlanguage/` to a seperate controller:

```
class SetLanguageController extends Controller {

    public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

        $requestedLanguage = $request->param('Language'); //as defined in config below
        $languageCookie = new Cookie;
        $languageCookie->set('site_language', $requestedLanguage);

        return $this->RedirectBack();

    }
}
```

We don't need to define `$allowed_actions` in this case, cause action index is allowed by default.

Now in your */mysite/_config/routes.yml* you have to define the route to your controller:

```
---
Name: mysite-routes
After: framework/routes#coreroutes
---

Director:
  rules:
    'setlanguage/$Language': 'SetLanguageController'
```

See also: [Docs for routing](http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/controllers/routing/)